# R file for custom component not compiling

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have two custom components, one which I made quite recently, both in Android Studio. The earlier one worked. I followed the same procedure to make the new one but it throws runtime errors when I reach the activity screen during testing.

These are the exception messages, listed in order:

```
1. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sentient/com.mycompany.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
2. Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
3. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
4. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mycomponent.R$color
```

Error #4 shows the actual line itself that throws the error, it is part of the constructor of the component:

```
int color = res.getColor(R.color.progress_gray);
```

I checked the R file manually, and found the colors (`progress_gray` is defined in the `colors.xml`) to be present. I removed the line, and another line throws the error instead (which again depends on the R file to get information).

I have tried cleaning, changing build order in gradle, Make the component separately, and I still can't figure out where the mistake is. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you're not importing android.R but yourApp.R

Answer (score 1):

can you post the xml file of the custom view?

Check if you have added  to your main layout of the custom view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. The applicationId in build.gradle and the package in the manifest were not matching. Once I changed it, it worked.

Strange though, I had thought that the reason the two were separated was so that they could be named differently. In any case, that was what got it working.